# Why does a battery starts working on rubbing?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics

Whenever my TV remote or wireless keyboard/mouse stops working,I take the batteries out and rub the two terminals with some rough cloth and it works fine.I've observed that this works a lot of times(not always).

What is the reason for this?

I'm guessing that some sort of thin oxide layer might have deposited on the battery terminals which I'm removing by rubbing it with rough cloth surface.Am I correct?

What might be other reasons for this phenomenon?

Comment: Does it keep working for a long time, or is it simply heat transfer that makes the batteries work for a very short time?

Comment: I usually do something similar with my wireless mouse. But I don't need to rub the terminals. All I do is remove the battery for a few seconds (10s or so). When I plug it in, the mouse works for several minutes more, maybe an hour, then the battery dies again. That works a few times, but then I know it's time to change the batteries. If I measure with a DMM, the battery voltage is low when connected, but when I disconnect it, its voltage raises quite a bit. Does this somehow help get the battery last breath? Why?

Comment: @David:Normally yes.I had done this with my keyboard last night before searching about it & typing the question.
But sometimes it's a sign that the batteries need to be replaced.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, it sounds like some kind of dirt gets between the battery terminals and the holder terminals.  Batteries shouldn't be made of a material that oxidizes easily in air, and neither should the holder for exactly this reason.  However, I have seen holders made from just copper, which certainly can oxidize in air.  Good holders are usually nickle-plated steel, which keeps working for a long time.  Nickle is relatively inert in air.

Do you live someplace with high pollution or near the ocean?  Even just a little H<sub>2</sub>S over time can corrode things.

Comment: No I live an a cantonment area with lots of greenery.No pollution here.

In the comments Ricardo has raised a point I've also observed.whats the reason for it?

I'm guessing that it might be due to loading?Am I correct?